# How can I delete a project in visual studio and keep the source code?

Tags: visual-studio

When I finished a small project, I want to delete the project because the whole project is so large(compared to my source code) that keeping it is a waste of memeory. I can do it manually but I wonder if there is an automatical way that will make this easier and faster?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the SLN file only , and you will have deleted the solution file or copy source code somewhere else